# How to Remove Spacing between ItemsControl Items

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl with materialDesign Chips as a DataTemplate. My goal is to place the items one after the other without a lot of space in between.

There is a pic what is now looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JLmH.png

And this is my Goal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N22BP.png

I tried already the ItemContainerStyle with Margin but this didnt helped me out

My Current Code

```cs
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsControl x:Name="myItemsControl" Height="40" Margin="0 10 0 0">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <materialDesign:Chip Tag="{Binding Name}" Uid="{Binding SourceName}" Content="{Binding Code}" Width="75" IsDeletable="True" DeleteClick="Chip_DeleteClick"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Try to use `StackPanel` with `Orientation=Horizontal` instead of `UniformGrid`

Comment: A UniformGrid will always space out the items depending on its width, use a StackPanel as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks Guys! This is what I was looking for

Comment: @Mitya please answer questions with an actual answer instead of in comments. Otherwise, no one can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ItemsPanelTemplate` to `StackPanel` instead of `UniformGrid`

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```